# boundary of cone operation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In The Bredon at the beginning of the chapter Subdivions (homology theory) there is the following construction:
for $v \in \Delta_q$ define: $ v: L_p(\Delta_q) \to L_{p+1}(\Delta_q)$ (where $L$ is generated by the affine simplicies). by $[v_0,...,v_p] \mapsto [v,v_0,...,v_p]$. Then the claim is that for $p>0: \delta v[v_0,...,v_p] = [v_0,...,v_p] - v(\delta [v_o,...,v_p]) $. This equation I do understand just by definition of the boundary operator. But why does this not hold for $p=0$ and moreover the book claims that for $p=0$ we have $\delta vc= c-\varepsilon(c)[v]$, where $\varepsilon$ is the augmentation i.e it sends a 0 chain to the sum of its coefficients. I absolutly dont understand why the last equation should be true, what $\varepsilon(c)[v]$ should mean and why the first one is not true for $p=0$. Moreover this augmentation appears some time in this book but I never really liked it or understood why Bredon is using it. So if someone can explain me what is the meaning of that I would also be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $p$-chain $c = \sum_\sigma n_\sigma \sigma$ we have $vc  = \sum_\sigma n_\sigma v \sigma$.

For $p = 0$ we have $\sigma = [v_0]$ and $v\sigma = [v, v_0]$. Hence
$$\partial v\sigma = \partial [v, v_0] = [v_0] - [v] = \sigma - [v].$$
Here $[v]$ is the $0$-simplex with vertex $v$.

Given a $0$-chain $c = \sum_\sigma n_\sigma \sigma$ we get

$$\partial vc = \partial \left(\sum_{i=1}^k  n_\sigma v \sigma\right) = \sum_\sigma n_\sigma\partial v\sigma =  \sum_\sigma n_\sigma(\sigma - [v]) =  \sum_\sigma n_\sigma \sigma -  \sum_\sigma n_\sigma[v] \\= c -  \left(\sum_{i=1}^k  n_\sigma \right) [v] = c -\epsilon(c)[v] .$$